# Why do I have these paths in Intellij IDEA console?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

I've just installed IDEA on my new PC and when I try to run my project, before the result I see these paths:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\JetBrains\IntelliJ_IDEA_Community_Edition_2019.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55779:C:\JetBrains\IntelliJ_IDEA_Community_Edition_2019.3.3\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Hor\IdeaProjects\HF Java\out\production\HF Java" Ch3.
>
> 14 //result
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I didn't have that on my previous PC. How do I solve the problem? I'd like not to see this 'pathway' line..

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What do you expect to see/not see?

Comment: That's the command that IntelliJ uses to run your application, you can ignore that.

Comment: I mean, I'd like not to see this line with C:\Program Files... , like it was on my previous pc. So that's why I'm asking how could I remove it...

Comment: Which version of IDEA did you have on your previous PC? Do you have any screenshots of how previous output looked like?

Comment: I had the same version 2019.3.3 (Community Edition). Unfortunately, I don't have a screenshot, I just can say that instead of these paths I had a result (14, like in example, for instance) followed by the "Process finished with exit code 0" line and that's all..

Comment: Guys, thank you to everybody for the answers! I guess my question is really dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit setting responsible for displaying the system message in the 'Run' tool window (`Alt+4`) - other than **File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors** > 'Console' section > 'System output' option.

However, if you run your application via the 'Services' tool window (`Alt+8`), the system message will be partially folded and faded:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I found out that my question is stupid indeed and that's not an error or something..

Comment: No worries @Lawbich, happy to help.